# Same transaction for database and activemq

Tags: database, transactions, jms, activemq-classic, messagebroker

I want to produce a message after database CRUD action. Is there any solution to share database transaction with an `activemq` instance? This `activemq` instance at least has two producer App and two concumer app.

Comment: Maybe you can, depends on framework and database. You need to use XA transactions. Typically any JTA compliant transaction manager can be used to do this. Some Java EE app servers comes with this OOTB other require some work. Anyhow, this question is by far too broad. Make some research on your framework/app server/database together with XA/JTA transactions and come back with more specific questions, if needed.

Comment: I agree with Petter, here. This certainly is possible (e.g. using the Wildfly Java EE application server) assuming your database supports XA transactions. However, you don't indicate what kind of environment you're in so it's really impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I want to use the application transaction in activemq, therefore there is one resource (that share between app and activemq). I don't want to use XA transaction.